# Single user api fetch, flutter

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-getx

I only want to fetch/get single `api` data, i tried to print the response from `service` i got all the  `api` data but when i try to pass it to the `controller` the variable for model didn't correct,
i already look for the anwser for fetching single api with `Service` and `Controller` architecture with `GetX` but i didn't find any suitable answer, i hope you can help me it's very important. thanks

im using `http` and `GetX`

> the problem is here

```
 var user = <UserModel>{}.obs;
    user.value = _user;
```

it tells

> UserModel _user A value of type 'UserModel' can't be assigned to a
> variable of type 'Set'. Try changing the type of the
> variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Set

here is the code

> Api Service

```
class ApiService {
  Future<UserModel> fetchApi(id) async {
    var url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users/$id';

    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var dataResponse = jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];

    UserModel user = UserModel.fromJson(dataResponse);

    return user;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed Get API');
    }
  }
}
```

> Controller

```
class Controller extends GetxController {
  var user = <UserModel>{}.obs;

  Future fetchApi(id) async {
    try {
      var _user = await ApiService().fetchApi(id);
      user.value = _user;
      print(user);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

> Model

```
class UserModel {
  int id;
  String email;
  String name;
  String avatar;
  UserModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
    required this.name,
    required this.avatar,
  });

  factory UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserModel(
        id: json['id'],
        email: json['email'],
        name: json['first_name'] + ' ' + json['last_name'],
        avatar: json['avatar'],
      );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason is that you are defining user as {} type and you need UserModel Type.

You need change this:

```
var user = <UserModel>{}.obs;
user.value = _user;
```

for this:

```
var user = UserModel().obs;
user.value = _user;
```

Comment: but i had contructor in UserModel, what should i fill the constructor with in  var user = UserModel(id: ?, email: ?, name: ?, avatar: ?);

Comment: You can modify your constructor from positional arguments to name arguments or set as null satefy your attributes.